# Facebook SDK 4 for Android - how to log out programmatically

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Recently, Facebook released SDK 4 with new and cool updates. I tried to switch into SDK4 to use new features, however, I am struggling with the Login feature of Facebook.

So far, to log out Facebook programmatically, I used :

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
```

But SDK4 seems not to support Session anymore, and in official docs, they mention:

> There are two ways to implement Facebook login on Android:
>
> LoginButton class - Which provides a button you can add to your UI. It follows the current access token and can log people in and out.

Well, seems there's no way to log out Facebook programmatically except using LoginButton.
Anyone have any idea, please share it here.

Answer (score 289, accepted):

You can use `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();`, even if you use LoginButton because

> This UI element wraps functionality available in the LoginManager.

**EDIT:**
Just to mention that this works for **Facebook SDK v4**. I don't know if they will change it in the future.

@as batoutofhell mention, don't forget to put `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());` to initialize the facebook sdk. Please see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3) for the details.

Comment: I want to mention since this is the top google result, my app crashed when trying to log out until I added this line first:

FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
 LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

Comment: After logout it won't allow me to Login again. Is there any way to login again after I did LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

Comment: Thanks a lot @stackex , this was very helpful and time saving

Comment: Why should we call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize, as it has already been initialized in onCreate?

Comment: its not working for me ..... in facebook once login via my app but i m trying to logout user but again clicking on facebook button its showing that you are logged in ..... do u want to logout or cancel why ?

Comment: @erum did you figure out your problem? I am having the same one.

Comment: LoginManager.logOut() i used this  , it works properly

Comment: @Erum There is no such method `LoginManager.logOut()` as of now in FB SDK v4.23.0

Comment: That works, unlike FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut(). The last is working for google sign in only for some reason...

Answer (score 68):

SDK4, if you want to completely de-couple, make sure you also remove the app from the user's facebook account. This method disconnects the user completely:

```
public void disconnectFromFacebook() {

    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
        return; // already logged out
    }

    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest
            .Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

        }
    }).executeAsync();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted!

Comment: That mean I must remove Facebook App and Facebook message to completed logout for my app ?

Comment: This answer ensures the user completly logged out. Just to be 100% it is needed to include FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

Comment: In the callback I also added @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            }

Comment: what does .logOut() do? Is it asynchronous? Will it block my UI thread for some millisecs? I think that .logOutAsync() would make more sense

Comment: @voghDev onCompleted does not come back on the UI thread I believe, so it does not block it when you call logOut there.

Comment: In my case `onCompleted` hasn't been called, so I used an accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you. This is what exactly I am looking for.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `LoginManager.logOut()`

Check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager/

Comment: That works if you're using LoginManager. Is there a way to logout programmatically when using LoginButton?

Comment: I also want to know how we can logout when using LoginButton

Comment: just use the LoginButton, click it again then it will be logged out

Answer (score 8):

To handle it with the loginButton:

```
//Check if user is currently logged in
        if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null && com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null){
            //Logged in so show the login button
            fbLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
//log out
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                    gotoLogin();
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Hey Stevie, When i called logOut() method as you have mentioned in your answer then it gave me error "java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0;". It is asking me to add a permission in manifest file. How can i resolve it because i dont want to give this permission as logout should be normal procedure.

Comment: @Aditya You only need the internet permission for the App. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: But i am getting above error, if i dont add it. If possible, can you please share a facebook sample which has custom login button and custom logout button ??

Comment: @Aditya in this example I am using the facebook Login button

Answer (score 5):

You can logout by using LoginManager but you have to use graph request also. I am talking about log out completely so, that next time you can login with different account.

```
new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest
            .Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

            SharedPreferences pref = DashBoard.this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

            Intent logoutint = new Intent(DashBoard.this,MainActivity.class);
            logoutint.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
               startActivity(logoutint);

        }
    }).executeAsync();
```

By the help of shared preferences here you can logout completely, and next time you can login with different account.

Answer (score 1):

Frank version kotlin:

```
 fun disconnectFromFacebook() {
    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
        return  // already logged out
    }
    GraphRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        "/me/permissions/",
        null,
        HttpMethod.DELETE,
        GraphRequest.Callback {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()
        }).executeAsync()
}
```