# How to force android facebook sdk to re-authenticate

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

**Short version**: I want my app to somehow delete/reset the Facebook Apps on the same device, so that after logout it will always ask people to login in Facebook Apps and forget all the account history to maintain the privacy.

**Long version:**
I am building an android apps that do a specific tasks like this:

1. The apps will capture an image
2. The apps will ask user to login into Facebook (e.g. Facebook integration)
3. The apps will then try to share the captured image via user's Facebook account
4. The apps will then automatically logout the current user account

I follow Android Facebook SDK documentation to build the login features. It stated that my device must have Facebook Application installed so I did install it, and everything are well.

The image sharing was going well.

But then I want my app to logout the current Facebook Account completely. I followed the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29305232/facebook-sdk-4-for-android-how-to-log-out-programmatically) by using the following code:

```
public void disconnectFromFacebook() {

    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
        return; // already logged out
    }

    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest
            .Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

        }
    }).executeAsync();
}
```

It did logout, but the Facebook Account that already logged in at the Facebook Apps will remain intact. Then when another user want to login, a scene [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKQEy.png) will popup, indicating that the Facebook Apps save the account history and did not Logged out completely.

Since my Apps will be deployed on public places where people can freely capture photos and share it to Facebook via my Apps, I want my Apps to always Logout the Facebook Account permanently from my device. This means that, when the next people use my Apps I want it to ask a brand new Facebook Login authentication without the Facebook Apps remembering every person that logged to it.

I already try some of the workaround:

1. I suppress the facebook login to use webview as stated from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginBehavior/),
   this solution seems to always ask a login authentication, but then
   it will also redirect to Facebook Apps so it is pointless.
2. I am thinking to share the image via web application, but not only it will be unable to share automatically using my code, the callback will not reach my application. Plus, the documentation also stated that all sharing task must be done using Facebook SDK.

Sorry should I not compile my question better.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the verification using web APIs instead of the Personal App, Facebook login with Mobile Application is intended for private users only. Here is a full [facebook 4.0.+ login example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605236/cant-get-location-and-email-using-facebook-api/29605975#29605975).

Comment: The web APIs solve the problem, now it always ask a user to login, and `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();` works well with it.

But since the Facebook web APIs did not accept binary to parse with, I can't attach images to it. But I can still share a link with a quote.

Since the re-authentication process was succesfully obtained, I think I will take a workaround to save the image elsewhere and share the image's link to Facebook.

Thankyou for the solution.